# Redirect the page to new webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one.html and two.html, my requirement is when user enters the url for one.html, a dialog box with message saying "You are redirected to the new Web page" should be displayed and user can click ok button to continue or within 10 seconds the dialog box should close automatically and user should redirect to the new page(two.html). Please suggest.

**PS:** I can able to get the result to some extent but the issue is i can able to see one.html and the dialog box on it, whereas users should not see one.html, only the dialog box with message and ok button should be dispalyed to the users and after 10 seconds if user is not clicking ok button , it should redirect to two.html page.

Answer (score 0):

Place this script inside one.html. The code is self-explanatory.

```
<script>
function redirectToPage2(){
    var redirectUrl = "two.html"
    message= "You will be redirected to Page 2. Click <a href='"+redirectUrl+"'>here</a> if you are not redirected in 10 seconds.";
    $(body).innerHTML=message;  
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location=redirectUrl;
        }, 10000);  // will redirect after 10 seconds
    }
}
window.onload = redirectToPage2;
</script>
```

If you don't want to see one.html at all, you will need another page - say three.html. And the code will look like this.

One.html

```
<script>
    window.onload = "Three.html";
</script>
```

And place the above code in Three.html.

Comment: I dont want to show the content of one.html to the users, it should display a dialog box or alert box with message on it and user can click ok button to proceed or within 10 seconds the dialog box/alert box should close automatically and display two.html page.

Comment: Please look at the second part of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the support but it's not working, before loading one.html it should display dialog box with message on it and after 10 seconds or once user click OK page should redirect to another page. This is because my old web page has been modified to new page so when user gives the old url in browser just want to display the dialog box with message without loading the old content and then show the new web page.

Comment: Yes. That is why from page 1, you should redirect to a medium page - page 3 which will show the counter and redirect to page 2.

Comment: so, page1 contains my old html code and window.onload="three.html" and in three.html I will have a code to show dialog box and redirection to two.html and in two.html my new html code. I tried in the same way but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

If your target is just to redirect viewers of one.html to two.html, you could try this code:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;two.html">`

or if your planning to load something before redirecting, try this:

```
<script language=javascript>
function redirect(){
  // do stuffs
  window.location = "two.html";
}
</script>
<body onload="redirect()">
  <!-- your content -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**one.html**

```
<script src="jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script>

window.onload = function myFunction() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to redirect with two.html page ?") == true) {
        window.location.href="two.html";
    } 
}
</script>
```

**Explanation :**

- Include javascript file that is required.
- window.onload = When a Web page is loaded, the code on the page — whether HTML, CSS, PHP, or some other type.
- confirm() method = The confirm() method displays a dialog box with a specified message, along with an OK and a Cancel button.
- If user press on OK button then it will redirect to two.html page with the use of function "window.location.href"

Comment: Requirement is not just a redirect, I don't want to show the content of the old web page. does visibility options of div works?? pls suggest.

Answer (score 0):

-- Add This CSS In header

```
<style>
    body
    {
        display:none;
    }
 </style>
```

That Might Be helpful....